# Stopping function processing externally

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I have a huge problem. I am working in a Web Python Project, where, after click in a button, a specific controller is called and then another function, present in a python module, is called as well, as shown in my code below. However , I need a second button that stops the process of the **stream function controller**.

```
import analyser
def stream():
    analyser.get_texts()
    response.flash = "Analysis Done."
    return ""
```

I've been searching a lot how to stop a process by an external event (something similar to interruption), but the solutions that I've got, all of them, were about how to stop python script using **sys.exit()** ou programatically by a **return statement**, for example. None of these solutions actually work for me.

I want that the user be able to stop that function whenever he wants, once that my function *analyser.get_texts()* remains processing all the time.

So, my question is how can I stop the execution of **stream** function, through a button click on my view? Thanks.

Comment: are that funciton on a diferent thread from the main one?

Comment: @Netwave The flow happens in that direction: my application starts, so after user click on a buttton the **function controller stream** is called, and after my python module function **get_texts()**. So I guess that they are in the same thread. I didn't code using a multithreading approach.

Comment: then why are you tagging as `multithreading?`

Comment: Because I intended to use multithreading, but I was not sure if was the proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then your analyser doesn't provide its own way to terminate an ongoing calculation. You will therefore need to wrap it into something that allows you to terminate the analyser without its "consent".

The right approach for that depends on how bad terminating the analyser in that way is: does it leave resources in a bad state?

Depending on that, you have multiple options:

- Run your analysis in a separate process. These can be cleanly killed from the outside. Note that it's usually not a good idea to forcefully stop a thread, so use processes instead.
- Use some kind of asynchronous task management that lets you create and stop tasks (e.g. Celery).

Comment: Florian I get your explanation, but I still have some doubts. In the documentation of multiprocessing says: *Note that the start(), join(), is_alive(), terminate() and exitcode methods should only be called by the process that created the process object*. I thought in call **terminate()**, however, that call must be performed only by the process that created the "child" process. This doesn't fulfill my requirement.

Comment: If you run your analyzer in a separate process via the `multiprocessing` module then you *are* the one who creates the process, so it's totally fine to use `terminate`. Note however, that `terminate` only sends `SIGTERM`, which processes may ignore, so depending on how your analyzer is written you may use `os.kill` to send `SIGKILL` to the process instead. But try `Process.terminate` first.